# React native open image picker in customized layout

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building android app in react native. Here I can building image upload feature.

I want to open local image gallery in customized layout, which has two tabs in bottom, one from pick image from camera and another from local library, like instagram app has.

I have tried `react-native-image-picker` and `react-native-image-crop-picker`. But did not found this feature in these both react native packages.

Please guide me how can I create this feature.

Comment: You can create your own modal with buttons and your preferred design, then you can call these [react-native-image-picker functions](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker#directly-launching-the-camera-or-image-library) on your button's `onPress` listener.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried this package. This directly open camera or library. How can I design own modal.

Comment: You can read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) for Modal related queries.